# OAuth2 Authentication fails when using grant type "client_credentials"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have created an authorization server using OAuth2, currently, I am able to get a bearer token when calling:

```
POST /oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&amp;client_id=user-service&amp;client_secret=userServicePassword&amp;scope=server HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1002
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic dXNlci1zZXJ2aWNlOnVzZXJTZXJ2aWNlUGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

I use the returned token and make a request to the resource server like this:

```
POST /users/create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1002
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 7ba026a4-2ae2-46be-8bd6-65d4aeb09dac
{
    "username":"nicolasmanic",
    "password":"12345",
    "authorities":["ADMIN", "USER"]
}
```

But I get

```
{
  "timestamp": 1496657103659,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "exception": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/users/create"
}
```

My OAuth2AuthorizationConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String STORY_SERVICE_PASSWORD = "storyServicePassword";
    private static final String USER_SERVICE_PASSWORD = "userServicePassword";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(new InMemoryTokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager) //Enable password grant type.
                .userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("browser")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password")
                .scopes("ui")
                .and()
                .withClient("story-service")
                .secret(STORY_SERVICE_PASSWORD)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("server")
                .and()
                .withClient("user-service")
                .secret(USER_SERVICE_PASSWORD)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("server");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
```

My WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@Order(101)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userDetailsService;

        /*
        * Authenticate all urls except from home {/} and /login/* etc.
        * */
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/","/login").permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
```

and finally my Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/current", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Principal getUser(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('server')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        userService.create(user);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I am configuring wrong?

**EDIT**

Also here is the stacktrace:

```
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/users/create]
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Looking up handler method for path /users/create
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Returning handler method [public void gr.personal.auth.controller.UserController.createUser(gr.personal.auth.domain.User)]
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Read [class gr.personal.auth.domain.User] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3dc82e6a]
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Resolving exception from handler [public void gr.personal.auth.controller.UserController.createUser(gr.personal.auth.domain.User)]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Resolving exception from handler [public void gr.personal.auth.controller.UserController.createUser(gr.personal.auth.domain.User)]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Resolving exception from handler [public void gr.personal.auth.controller.UserController.createUser(gr.personal.auth.domain.User)]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - Could not complete request
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at gr.personal.auth.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b0fa6c15.createUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
2017-06-05 14:17:45 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/error]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

I completed removed my *WebSecurityConfig*. I extended the *GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter* as:

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalAuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> userRepository
                .findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

I believe that the issue has with my *Autowiring* of *userService*. I used to autowire it to the interface and not the concrete class (userServiceImpl) that was implementing the *UserDetailsService*.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` to your OAuth2AuthorizationConfig class.

Comment: I had it in my Application class, moved it OAuth2AuthorizationConfig class but made no difference. I still get 403 Access Denied

Comment: in this case, maybe changing `.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");`  from `.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");`  would do it

Comment: fyi, it does not matter where you put @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity by the way, as long as it is in a class that has Configuration annotation or something similar

Comment: No luck, I am still able to get the token using client_credential grant type, but whenever I try to access the controller with that token I get access denied.

Comment: I also added the stacktrace of the exception if it helps

Comment: Found it after digging into the spring security code! I has using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` and not @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity. Now I have another problem my endpoint is not secured, it accepts requests without the Authorization header. Any ideas??

Comment: I think you should add `@EnableResourceServer` which configures a filter automatically for you